# Как убрать папку module от Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, браузер

Я попытался поискать, но ничего не нашел, запускал webpack и в продакшн моде так и девелопмент, при переходе в консоль разработчика, а затем в [отладчик || Source], в каждом браузере называются по своему, можно видеть данную папку. Как исправить это?

[image: папка webpack которую нужно скрыть]

```
"webpack": "^5.25.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
```

Comment: Никак, а зачем? Вебпак тут ни при чём

Comment: @peter andreymal, потому что браузер говорит что это папка от него.

ps. я кажется понял, что я коротнул.